How to Convert Hexadecimal String into Hexadecimal Array of JavaScript to write characteristics into BLE device
I was building web app for vending machine that uses BLE protocol when connection is successful.
It has to send handshake command this is the documentation: "After
the Bluetooth connection is successful, the first part begins to carry out the handshake protocol of the application layer, which requires the applet to send a string of handshake codes.
X06 x8e (0, 0 XFB, 0, 0 x17, x0c, 0, 0 xa9 x68 0, 0 x23, 0 x7b, 0 x4c, 0 xd2, 0 x2d, 0 XDF, 0 xfa, 0 x66, 0 x5b, 0 x4f, 0 xe8) 

To Bluetooth to the vending machine hardware, vending machine hardware Bluetooth chip data for approval"
How to write characteristics using  these codes in JavaScript?
I tried to convert like this but nothing works
  const sendCommand = async (commandArray) => {
    if (writeCharacteristic) {
      try {
        const command = new Uint8Array(commandArray);
        console.log('Sending command:', commandArray);
        await writeCharacteristic.writeValue(command);
        console.log('Command sent:', command);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending command:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  const handshake = async () => {
    const handshakeCode =[
      0x06, 0x8e, 0xfb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17, 0x0c, 0xa9, 0x68, 0x23, 0x7b, 0x4c, 0xd2, 0x2d, 0xdf, 0xfa, 0x66, 0x5b, 0x4f, 0xe8    ]
    
    await sendCommand(handshakeCode);
  };


